# Android NoteList sample program

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In Android's sample NoteList application, inside the NotesList Activity on the onCreate method, a new Intent called intent is created which is assigned the return Intent from the method call "getIntent()" From my understanding this allows this particular Activity to have been activated by something other than clicking on the icon from the apps list. My question then would be, how can I test this theory? How can I launch the NotesList application other than through the main launcher? How can I tell what other applications can launch this Activity?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

About `Intents`:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

For starters, read the android tutorials:

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html